# Wordpress network admin builds wrong path when adding new blog

Tags: wordpress, debian

I am running `wordpress 3.2.2` on `debian`, which was installed via `aptitude install wordpress`. For some time, I used wordpress with a single blog, which worked fine. Then I "upgraded" to the new network of blogs feature via the wordpress dashboard. The semi-automatic procedure seemed to run fine and i made the suggested changes to `/etc/wordpress/config-xxx.php`, `/etc/wordpress/htaccess`, etc.

Now, if I create a new blog via the network administrator, even the building of a correct path to the new blog fails. If i add a blog named "test", the following URL is generated: `hxxp://xxx.comwordpresstest/wp-admin/`
Subsequently, all access to the new blog fails.

After some googeling and checking `.htaccess` I am stuck. Could anybody please give me some pointer in the right direction?

Comment: Your error was using the built-in upgrade function. If you install something using a tool, you should use the same tool to upgrade/remove. The correct action should be `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer, which is solely based on commenting on the word "upgrade" and ignoring my description, doesn't lead to a solution. Please note that "network of blogs" is a internal wordpress feature, which cannot be installed/activated/upgraded to via apt. However it might be possible that i left out some debian specific adaptions to the configuration or missed somethig else...

Comment: Do not install wordpress by using repositories. It will not give you the latest version. You have installed `3.2.2` and the latest version is `3.8`. Installing it from http://wordpress.org/ might solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not answering your question, I'm commenting on the error that is using different tools for installation and for upgrade. Package manager are quite sensible so if you installed using `sudo apt-get install wordpress` you should have used `sudo apt-get upgrade`. That way you should have been sure that the upgrades are applied correctly.